# Distributed Cache Service Accounts

Tags: best-practices, cache

Recently saw a health warning in my 2013 CA that stated:

The farm account is used for the SharePoint timer 
service and the central administration site, it is highly privileged and should 
not be used for any other services on any machines in the server farm.  The 
following services were found to use this account: Distributed Cache 
Service(Windows Service)

Remedy: 
Browse to http://myserver.com/_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx and 
change the account used for the services listed in the explanation. For more 
information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142685".

I don't see any issues with creating another managed account for DC but 
didn't see any recommendations for what it could affect or impact, by doing so.

I found this peice talking about 
how to change it with powershell, scratching my head on if i should use this 
method or the one in the health warning if i do change it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx#changesvcacct

Comment: Got a reply to this over here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/daf29d10-e51c-437f-963b-204add51304e/#daf29d10-e51c-437f-963b-204add51304e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the reason to change the account, the only way how to do it is using powershell. If you try to change in CA (as suggested by health warning) you will get error that it is not supported for Ditributed Cache service.